# deep learning for stock prediction

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, time-series

I am learning deep learning . Right now I am using MNIST data set, which contains tens of thousands of scanned images of handwritten digits, together with their correct classifications.

My question how to use time series data like stock market data (how to incorporate stock data with neural networks )

My second question how to know which neural networks is suitable for predicting ?

Comment: Your question, as it is now, is very broad, and is basically asking about a whole field.  Also, there is plenty of information available online (googling "deep learning for stock prediction" gives thousands of results, including tutorials and scientific articles studying the matter; further googling "deep learning for stock prediction github" gives source code examples). Have you checked any sources before asking? Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: @noe  I am just asking the logic/principle behind using time series data instead of images/audio in first layer of neural network . I know the hands-on procedure

Comment: agree with @noe that the question is too broad. Suggest to close and to OP, GIYBF.